# Replacing text in table via overlay causes table to move: beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I am using beamer and trying to change a word in a table via overlays. So, "constant" should appear on some slides and "non-constant" should appear on other slides---both in the *same* box.  (This same box makes this question different from others asked, I think.)

When I do it with onslide, beamer reserves room for both words which is not what I want---it makes for ugly table spacing.  When I do it with only, however, beamer moves the table downward during the word change.  I am including what I think is a minimal example of this latter phenomena.  (The former is standard.) Note that if I eliminate the first row of the table (the one above my problematic line) and instead put in a row below the problematic line, the problem goes away.  (Just reporting in case it helps people figure this out.)

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Test}
\onslide<2->{
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c || c c c c |}
\hline
& P4 & \onslide<1->{P3} &\onslide<1->{P2} & \onslide<1->{P1} \\ \hline
\only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}}  Cognition 1 & \only<6>
{\cellcolor{yellow}} $(a,c_{*})$ & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\onslide<1->{Constant} & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \onslide<1-
{Constant} & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \onslide<1->{Constant} \\
\only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \only<1-7>{Cognition 2}\only<8>
{\alert{Cognition 3}}\only<9->{\alert{Cognition 4}} & \only<5>
{\cellcolor{yellow}} $(a,c_{*})$ & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} 
\onslide<1->{$(a,b_{*})$} & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \only<1-7,9>
{Constant}% 
\only<8>{\alert{Non-Constant}} & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} 
\only<1-8>{Constant}%
\only<9->{\alert{Non-Constant}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}   
\end{center}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your problem is consequence of to wide table when you replace word "Constant" with "Non-Constant", If you select smaller fonts (for example`\small` after `\begin{center}`) your problem disappear. This can be one of solution. You also can test if the reduction `tabcolsep` can help you. More tests I can't do since your MWE contain an error.

Comment: As @Zarko already said, the vertical jumping will go away if the table is small enough to fit on the frame. But then you still have horizontal jumping within the table, as the width of the columns changes. Two possibilities: columns with a fixed width `p{...}` or you reserve room for the "non" with `\phantom{Non-}`.

Comment: Thanks! The phantom results in the "constant" not centered.  The small works, but (a) its a bit too small and (b) as indicated, it still causes the horizontal jumping.  i'm keeping this for now, but would be interested if others have better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted inmy comments, cause of your problem is to wude table. You can sxhring it on two ways:

- use smaller font
- reduce the size of space between table columns.

It seem that use of `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` will give satisfactory result:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Test}
\onslide<2->{
\begin{center}\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{| c || c c c c |}
\hline
& P4 & \onslide<1->{P3} &\onslide<1->{P2} & \onslide<1->{P1} \\ \hline
\only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}}  Cognition 1 & \only<6>
{\cellcolor{yellow}} $(a,c_{*})$ & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\onslide<1->{Constant} & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \onslide<1-
{Constant} & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \onslide<1->{Constant} \\
\only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \only<1-7>{Cognition 2}\only<8>
{\alert{Cognition 3}}\only<9->{\alert{Cognition 4}} & \only<5>
{\cellcolor{yellow}} $(a,c_{*})$ & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\onslide<1->{$(a,b_{*})$} & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \only<1-7,9>
{Constant}%
\only<8>{\alert{Non-Constant}} & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\only<1-8>{Constant}%
\only<9->{\alert{Non-Constant}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Beside above possible solution let be mentioned one more:

- locally enlarged text width of frame.

This can be achieved also on different way. One possibility is to use the package ˛changepage`and its macro`adjustwidth`. In this case the code is

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usecolortheme{crane}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Test}
\onslide<2->{

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1em}{-1em}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c || c c c c |}
\hline
& P4 & \onslide<1->{P3} &\onslide<1->{P2} & \onslide<1->{P1} \\ \hline
\only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}}  Cognition 1 & \only<6>
{\cellcolor{yellow}} $(a,c_{*})$ & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\onslide<1->{Constant} & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \onslide<1-
{Constant} & \only<6>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \onslide<1->{Constant} \\
\only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \only<1-7>{Cognition 2}\only<8>
{\alert{Cognition 3}}\only<9->{\alert{Cognition 4}} & \only<5>
{\cellcolor{yellow}} $(a,c_{*})$ & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\onslide<1->{$(a,b_{*})$} & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}} \only<1-7,9>
{Constant}%
\only<8>{\alert{Non-Constant}} & \only<5>{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\only<1-8>{Constant}%
\only<9->{\alert{Non-Constant}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Amanda, I convert my comment to the above answer and also latter add third possible solution. See if any of proposed fulfil your expectation.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you---I tried the second of these and it works very nicely.